# Print char *desc struct member of different structs

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have completely different structs with single common member `char *desc` and I want to print them:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    float foo;
    char *desc;
};

struct bar {
    int barint;
    char *desc;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct foo ff[] = {
        { 1.1, "desc foo 1"}, { 2.2, "desc foo 2"}, { }
    };

    struct bar bb[] = {
        {1, "desc bar 1"}, {2, "desc bar 2"}, {3, "desc bar 3"}, { }
    };

    const struct foo *f = ff;
    const struct bar *b = bb; 
    int i;

    for (i = 0; f[i].desc; i++)
        printf("f[%d].desc: '%s'\n", i, f[i].desc);

    for (i = 0; b[i].desc; i++)
        printf("b[%d].desc: '%s'\n", i, b[i].desc);

    return 0;
}
```

```sh
$ ./a.out
f[0].desc: 'desc foo 1'
f[1].desc: 'desc foo 2'
b[0].desc: 'desc bar 1'
b[1].desc: 'desc bar 2'
b[2].desc: 'desc bar 3'
```

I'd like to have single macro/function which can take array of any of these structs as a parameter (there can be more than these two), and print `desc` member.

EDIT: defining macro is easy:

```
#define PRINT_DESC(obj) do { \
    for (i = 0; obj[i].desc; i++) \
        printf("obj[%d].desc: '%s'\n", i, obj[i].desc); \
} while (0)
```

**But I need something more generic.** I'd like `const struct bar *b` or `const struct foo *f` (or any other struct) assign to another internal library struct member and then do printing in the library via this library struct member. That member could be `void *`, but how to specify what struct to cast that pointer to?

Concrete example (sorry, not MCVE): planned to use it in [LTP](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp).

There is `struct tst_test` in [`tst_test.h`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/include/tst_test.h#L129), where I'd like to add `void *` pointer to struct, which has the same size as `int test_variants` member. And then print `*desc` of particular member in loop in [`tst_run_tcases()`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/lib/tst_test.c#L1401):

```
for (tst_variant = 0; tst_variant < test_variants; tst_variant++) {
    if (tst_test->test_variants_desc)
        // TODO: print .desc for tst_test->test_variants_desc[tst_variant]
```

`struct tst_test` is defined in tests, e.g. [`futex_wait02`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/testcases/kernel/syscalls/futex/futex_wait02.c#L75), where [`struct futex_test_variants`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/testcases/kernel/syscalls/futex/futex_wait02.c#L18) would be passed, because it has `char *desc` member (defined in [`futextest.h`](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/blob/master/testcases/kernel/syscalls/futex/futextest.h#L74)).

Other tests have different structs, that's why it cannot be pointer to `struct futex_test_variants`.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attmept?

Comment: If `ff` and `bb` have the same number of elements, then why not loop once and use the common index to output values from both structs?

Comment: Take these struct as completely different, only with `char *desc` in common. I haven't tried anything, I just have no clue.

Comment: Updated the question to more illustrate what I need to solve.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `_Generic` but tbh, it sounds like you simply picked the wrong language :)

Comment: But I don't think your question is very clear. Can you show exactly how you would like to call this function or macro?

Comment: Don't put it in comments. Edit the question and make sure it's self contained. And show a struct that doesn't work with the macro.

Comment: You do not buy anything working with `void` here, you would have to cast back to the appropriate type before you could dereference the pointer anyway, either with `*ptr` or `prt[x]`.